# How do I call a function when a segue is exited?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uistoryboardsegue

Currently, my app goes from view A to view B through a segue and performs some functions in prepareForSegue. What should I do if I want to call a function that is executed when view B goes to view A (after pressing the back button on the Navigation Controller)?

I imagine that I could map the "back button" to an IBAction, but I'm not sure how I would do that, since the back button is part of the Navigation Controller and isn't directly visible on the Storyboard.

In particular, view B updates some values that view A has displayed. I want to call viewDidLoad so that view A has the updated data before it loads.

In ViewA's view controller:

```
// update view when it becomes visible
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Yup, you can't do that.  See my edit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, this isn't a segue as such.  This is equivalent to popViewController.

If you want to update the view when view A becomes visible then you can do that in the function...

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

or in the function

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

These will run each time the view becomes visible.

In here you can run your "updateView" method or whatever method you want.

If you want to pass data back to view A (i.e. view B is a "select city" view or something) then you show make view A a delegate of view B.  That way you can pass the info back when the user does something.

Instead of running viewDidLoad do this...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.button setTitle:@"blah"];

    [self updateView];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self updateView];
}

- (void)updateView
{
    // do something that you want to happen
}
```

You shouldn't actually have to do this though.  It is enough just to run [self updateView] from viewDidAppear.

You can't run viewDidLoad directly though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, this doesn't seem to work completely for my application. When I go from View B back to View A, it looks like viewDidAppear does not get called, but when I go from View A back to the Main menu (which is also connected by a segue), it does. How do I get it so it works more consistently?

Comment: Your segue from A to B... is that a push segue or a modal segue?  How are you going from B back to A? Are you using the navigation bar back button or are you doing it in code?  If you are doing it in code can you paste the code?

Comment: It's a push segue, and I'm going back using the navigation bar back button.

Comment: Is there a way I could do [self.presentingViewController viewDidLoad] in the View B controller code? It doesn't seem to work. I also tried self.parentViewController.

Comment: Have you put viewDidAppear into your view A viewController? It should get run when it re-appears.

Comment: I did, but the code only works when I go from View B, to View A, then to the Main Menu, then back to View A. It doesn't work when I go from View B to View A directly.

Comment: Oh, I think you are using viewDidLoad.  You shouldn't use that.  That will only run once (i.e. when pushed to - when going from main menu to A).  You should use viewDidAppear.  This is not there by default, you need to put it in there (just in the .m).

Comment: That's what I did. I added an additional viewDidAppear in my .m file that calls a viewDidLoad. Sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: You need to use viewDidAppear but you can't call viewDidLoad from it.  You should never run viewDidLoad yourself. If you need to do some stuff in both then put it into a function like - (void)updateView and run THAT from viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear.

Comment: viewDidLoad is used for setting up things that won't change. Normally data objects etc... (e.g. maybe a userName or a title of a button, etc...) viewDidAppear is used to do things that need to happen every time you move to the view such as refreshing a tableView or updating a label with the latest time, etc...

Comment: I did what you just said, moving my update code into a separate function and calling that from viewWillAppear, and it didn't work. Same issue as before.

Comment: I GOT IT! thanks for your help. I needed to add [viewA setNeedsDisplay] for it to work.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted in the end :D

Answer (score 1):

In view controller "A" you need to implement the method `prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` and inside create a segues destinationViewcontroller, heres a example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:SEGUE_FOR_OPTIONS])
  {
     // Get reference to the destination view controller
      OptionsViewController *optionVC = [segue destinationViewController];
     [optionVC someMethod];
  } 
}
```